# Sql php session delete system

Tags: php, mysql

I make a php form that retrieve data from sql. select well and edit update well, but how can i click to delete this sql data. i try many time but maybe something wrong. please help me with this code

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6T3k.jpg]

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT * from tblclasses"; 
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql); 
$query->execute(); 
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
$cnt=1; 
if($query->rowCount() > 0) { 
   foreach($results as $result) { 
       ?> 
       <tr> <td><?php echo htmlentities($cnt);?></td> 
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($result->ClassName);?></td> 
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($result->CreationDate);?></td> 
            <td> <a href="edit-info.php?classid=<?php echo htmlentities($result->id);?>"><i class="fa fa-edit" title="Edit Record"></i> Edit</a> </td> 
       </tr> 
       <?php 
       $cnt=$cnt+1;
   }
} 
?>
```

Comment: Please don't post your code in an image. Please post it as text.

Comment: Please paste your code and don't bother with screenshots

Comment: you don't have a delete link. might be a start

Comment: why my code format not support here, i don't understand

Comment: Plus the code in that screenshot seems to be for editing only. _Show us_ what you have (supposedly) tried!

Comment: <?php $sql = "SELECT * from tblclasses";
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$cnt=1;
if($query->rowCount() > 0)
{
foreach($results as $result)
{   ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo htmlentities($cnt);?></td>
<td><?php echo htmlentities($result->ClassName);?></td>
<td><?php echo htmlentities($result->CreationDate);?></td>
<td>
<a href="edit-info.php?classid=<?php echo htmlentities($result->id);?>"><i class="fa fa-edit" title="Edit Record"></i> Edit</a> 
</td>
</tr>
<?php $cnt=$cnt+1;}} ?>

Comment: _“why my code format not support here”_ - you are supposed to show your code _in text form_ here, not just a screenshot of it. Please go read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: No, don’t post it as a comment either, that is hardly readable at all … _Edit_ your question, and insert it properly formatted.

Comment: ok i am trying to reedit it

Comment: _"i try many time"_ - you need to show _what_ you have tried, without that we can't tell what was wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Add another column in your table, with a delete link:

```
<td> 
    <a href="delete-info.php?classid=<?php echo htmlentities($result->id);?>">
        <i class="fa fa-remove" title="Delete Record"></i> Delete
    </a> 
</td>
```

Create `delete-info.php`. Check for `GET` var `classid`, then do your `DELETE` query!

Comment: i am beginner, please write some code for delete-info.php

Comment: `$sql ='DELETE FROM whatever_tablename WHERE whatever_id_column = ' . $classid;`